# How can this method be refactored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, stripe-payments

I'm building a small payment processing module for fun using Ruby on Rails and Stripe and I'd like to know how this method (used to check if a given user already has a card on file with Stripe) could be refactored:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
def has_card?
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_customer_id)
    if customer.cards.count > 0
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

I think the `if` statement looks silly but can't explain why (I'm not a dev by day, I only dabble)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is right, it is silly!

```
def has_card?
  Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id).cards.count > 0
end
```

Comment: AH! Guess I love to complicate things a bit :) Thanks!!